# BeanUtils.copyProperties() vs DozerBeanMapper.map()

Tags: java, mapping, dozer, apache-commons-beanutils

I am using [`BeanUtils.copyProperties()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) for bean to dto mapping when I need to map all fields and field names are same. But I need not all field of source bean to map in destination dto, I used  [`DozerBeanMapper.map()`](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dozer/DozerBeanMapper.html#map%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) , because I haven't idea about to use BeanUtils in this situation.

*So I think both methods having their own functionality, and there is no any similarity between both. Am I right? Please guide me.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might check out my [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org). It will intelligently map properties (fields/methods) even if the names are not exactly the same. Defining specific properties to be mapped or skipped is simple and uses real code instead of XML:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Order, OrderDTO>() {
  protected void configure() {
    map().setBillingStreet(source.getBillingStreetAddress());
    skip().setBillingCity(null);
  }
});
```

Check out the project homepage for more info:

http://modelmapper.org

Answer (score 6):

We considered mapstruct for our usecase. See a sample below:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

    To to(From from);

}
```

Here is a performance comparison of MapStruct against Selma, Orika, ModelMapper, Dozer and manual mapping:

[image: Manual mapping vs. Selma vs. MapStruct vs. Orika vs. ModelMapper vs. Dozer]

[Selma vs. MapStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786737/java-mapping-selma-vs-mapstruct)

Comment: Do you have anywhere comaprison between MapStruct and BeanUtils.copyProperties()?