# Selma v/s MapStruct v/s Model Mapper which one to chose as java mapping framework.?

Tags: mapping

Hi,
I am trying to use mapping framework in my project, but i am not able to decide which one to choose, among these three mapping frameworks.
Selma v/s MapStruct v/s Model Mapper mapping framework ?

Please help me to choose the best feature and performance oriented framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java mapping: Selma vs MapStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786737/java-mapping-selma-vs-mapstruct)

Comment: Related list of mappers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/

Answer (score 16):

In light of the Java 8 Stream APIs and with `lombok` annotation processor library, I am no longer using this mapping frameworks. I create my own mappers by implementing the `Converter` interface of the spring framework (`package org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`)

```
    @Component
    public class ProductToProductDTO implements Converter<Product, ProductDTO> {
        @Override public ProductDTO convert( Product source ) {
            ProductDTO to = ProductDTO.builder()
                    .name( source.getName())
                    .description( source.getDescription() )
                    .tags(source.getTags().stream().map(t -> t.getTag().getLabel()).collect( Collectors.toList()))
                            .build();
            return to;
        }
    }

    @Builder //lombok annotation to create Builder class
    @Data //lombok annotation to create getters & setters
    @AllArgsConstructor //required for @Builder
    public class ProductDTO  {
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private List<String> tags;
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever run a benchmark to compare it? Could you elaborate why you changed?

Comment: alltej: If you use this method for a DTO pattern, it adds quite a lot of complexity to your program because you have to create at least one converter every time you create a new DTO. If you also want to convert backwards, you will need 2 converters. In addition, you have to set each field manually, every time you create a new Dto. So for 10 dtos, you need to create a total of 30 files in the worst case. On top of that, let's say there are 10 fields for each dto, then you have to write 30*10 = 300 lines of code. It doesn't sound good.

Comment: @Nesd Agree. My response was to address the question with a given example.

Answer (score 8):

You can find a complete comparison between the most used frameworks to map when you click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks). In this link you can find benchmark comparisons, how to use each framework etc.
I decided to use MapStruct because it is easy to use and is so fast.

Answer (score 7):

I was in similar situation before while looking for solution to leverage annotation processors. I would go with either Selma or MapStruct. Kinda similar being code generators. Played with both but went with MapStruct. Similar question here in SO can help you - [Java mapping: Selma vs MapStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786737/java-mapping-selma-vs-mapstruct)

Also a project in github that benchmarked object to object mapper frameworks has Selma and MapStruct in the top - https://github.com/arey/java-object-mapper-benchmark

Comment: I was facing the same issue and the benchmark link helps a lot in making decision.

Comment: In light of the Java 8 Stream APIs, I am no longer using this mapping frameworks. I create my own mappers by implementing the `Converter` interface of the spring framework (`package org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`)

Comment: As a simple justification for some of those results: it is clear that compile-time mapping class generation (like `MapStruct`) is much faster than runtime mappers that use reflection (like `ModelMapper`).